# What is a two-word phrase for: acquaintances about whom we know nothing

Tags: phrase-requests

I need a two-word literary, good-sounding (I know, it sounds vague), and ironic phrase to say something like **unknown acquaintances**. I want two sides of the phrase to **contradict** each other. We have an ideal phrase for this in my native language and it sounds something like "people whom we **know** (acquaintances) whom we **don't know**." This phrase, however, sounds succinctly as "**tanı**madığımız **tanı**şlar" where "tanı" means to know/recognize. Now, I am searching for an English alternative of that phrase.

So, here is a bit of context: I am talking about speaker series and I want to invite people whom we meet routinely every single day but don't attempt to get to **know** them. Examples of such people may be gardeners, dining staff, waiters, police, janitors/janitresses etc.

Answer (score 1):

The technical term for such acquaintances is

**consequential strangers**

Here is a description from NPR:

> You get your coffee from your regular barista. You give a small nod to
>   the guy you see every day at the gym. You don't know these people, but
>   they're vital to your social landscape.

*(http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=112602248)*

It's not a very common idiom, but it's an oxymoron, so it does fit your requirement of being ironic or playful.

Otherwise, there are the more common stock phrases:

**distant acquaintances**

**passing acquaintances**

**nodding acquaintances** (implying you know them only well enough to nod at, but not speak to)